# Input checked state does not affect css selector

Tags: html, css, checkbox

So I've been trying to trigger my CSS selector via the checkbox state as you can see below but I've had no luck getting it to trigger. What should happen on click is the tick should simply disappear.

```
.i-cb input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
   display: none;
   width:0px;
   height: 0px;
}
```

**JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/7tnepc8r/4/

Comment: Since you are using the *adjacent sibling combinator* you are essentially targeting a `label` element that should directly follow the `input` element - which is not the case in the html structure demonstrated in the linked Fiddle. **CSS selectors - CSS | MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators **AND** *Adjacent sibling combinator - CSS | MDN:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with order.

You should change order your HTML.

The `+` selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after(not inside) the first specified element.

```css
.i-cb input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.i-cb label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border: 4px solid #48c8f1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.i-cb label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #93c83d;
  left: 22px;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.i-cb label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #93c83d;
  left: 10px;
  top: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.i-cb input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  display: none !important;
  width: 0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
} 

.i-cb input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="i-cb">
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="check"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but please also add *why* order makes a difference :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need change the markup order, because you using `+` sign which indicating label after input:

```
<div class="i-cb">
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="check"></label>
</div>
```